# Can't use mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

So, I'm getting this warning when using mysql_real_escape_string

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/path/php/functions.php on line 11
```

The rest of the site works fine, connects to the DB and all, but I get an error when using this function.

It works completely fine on my localhost testing server.

Any ideas?

I use aforementioned function in my own homebrew string sanitation function:

```
function sani($string){     
  $string = strip_tags($string); 
  $string = htmlspecialchars($string); 
  $string = trim(rtrim(ltrim($string))); 
  $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
  return $string;
}
```

And I use this function every time I do queries...

```
function mm_mysqlquery($query) {
 if (MM_DEBUG == true) { echo "Query: $query <br>"; mm_log("Query: $query"); } //print query if MM_DEBUG
 $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die ("mysql_error: " . mysql_error());
 $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
 return mysql_query($query, $link);
}
```

Thanks on beforehand!

Answer (score 8):

First point: If you're getting an error from `mysql_real_escape_string()`, it's because you are calling the function before you're connected to the database.

It looks like you connect to the database right before you run a query.  So anything you do before you call your `mm_mysqlquery()` function won't have a connection.

The `mysql_real_escape_string()` function needs a live connection to the database, so it can do the right kind of escaping with respect to the connection's character set.  So you need to connect *before* you do escaping.

It's better to do that anyway, because if you make several queries during the course of a single PHP request, it's less overhead to connect *once* and use the same connection for all your queries.

Second, please don't take suggestions to use `addslashes()` -- it does not do the same thing as `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  The two are not interchangeable.  You should get into the habit of using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Third, your `sani()` function shows a common misconception.

```
function sani($string){     
  $string = strip_tags($string); 
  $string = htmlspecialchars($string); 
  $string = trim(rtrim(ltrim($string))); 
  $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
  return $string;
}
```

The common misconception is that you need all these functions to make a string safe in an SQL statement.  You don't.  Only `mysql_real_escape_string()` is necessary.  All the other functions in this example do nothing to protect against SQL injection.

Those functions are useful if you output a string in an HTML presentation and you want to reduce the risk of XSS attacks, but then `mysql_real_escape_string()` is irrelevant.

Use each type of sanitizing method in its appropriate context.

Answer (score 0):

string mysql_real_escape_string  ( string $unescaped_string  [, resource $link_identifier  ] )

Where $unescaped_string is your string and $link_identifier is your db resource.

> The MySQL connection. If the link
>   identifier is not specified, the last
>   link opened by mysql_connect() is
>   assumed. If no such link is found, it
>   will try to create one as if
>   mysql_connect() was called with no
>   arguments. If no connection is found
>   or established, an E_WARNING level
>   error is generated.

[PHP.NET mysql_real_escape_string resource](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)